# How can i add SVG to PDF using Itext 7?

Tags: svg, itext

I am trying to add a sample SVG file using IText api. I am using latest version of iText but I am getting the below error. Below is the code to add svg. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue ?

Took the SVG File from here : Icons made by [Freepik](https://www.freepik.com/) from www.flaticon.com is licensed by CC 3.0 BY

Below is the POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/svg -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>svg</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Code

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\SVGPOC\\Sample1.pdf"));

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

URL svgUrl = new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\SVGPOC\\teamwork.svg").toURI().toURL();
doc.add(new Paragraph("Testing SVG on PDF"));                      
Image image = SvgConverter.convertToImage(svgUrl.openStream(), pdfDoc);
doc.add(image);
doc.close();


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.path.impl.MoveTo.setCoordinates(MoveTo.java:83)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.PathSvgNodeRenderer.processPathOperator(PathSvgNodeRenderer.java:205)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.PathSvgNodeRenderer.getShapes(PathSvgNodeRenderer.java:228)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.PathSvgNodeRenderer.doDraw(PathSvgNodeRenderer.java:115)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.draw(AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.java:121)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.AbstractBranchSvgNodeRenderer.doDraw(AbstractBranchSvgNodeRenderer.java:100)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.SvgTagSvgNodeRenderer.doDraw(SvgTagSvgNodeRenderer.java:62)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.draw(AbstractSvgNodeRenderer.java:121)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.renderers.impl.PdfRootSvgNodeRenderer.draw(PdfRootSvgNodeRenderer.java:93)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.converter.SvgConverter.convertToXObject(SvgConverter.java:816)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.converter.SvgConverter.convertToXObject(SvgConverter.java:663)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.converter.SvgConverter.convertToXObject(SvgConverter.java:653)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.converter.SvgConverter.convertToXObject(SvgConverter.java:688)
    at com.itextpdf.svg.converter.SvgConverter.convertToImage(SvgConverter.java:713)
    at demoitext.ITextDemo.main(ITextDemo.java:33)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7J/repos/itextcore/browse/svg/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/svg/renderers/path/impl/MoveTo.java?at=0d0539f7a51110a109142f61c06cacb2dbfee4e1#83) it seems that itext does not support move commands with more than 2 arguments.

> ```
>    if (coordinates.length > 2) {
>         // (x y)+ parameters will be implemented in the future
>         throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
>     }
> ```

The SVG specification allows this so you will simply have to rewrite your imput to avoid this i.e. insert an L or l command letter. So

```
M 1,2 3,4
```

would need to become

```
M 1,2 L 3,4
```

Comment: This is indeed the status as of iText 7.1.5, but it is fixed in develop (https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7J/repos/itextcore/browse/svg/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/svg/renderers/path/impl/MoveTo.java) so the user can build from source or wait for the next release (due in April).

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I will try to build the jar from the source you provided.

Comment: @blagae : Can you please let me know if the latest iText has been released ?

Comment: There's still 27 days in April. You can probably expect it by the end of the month.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. May i know if the latest version has been released ?

Comment: @blagae : Can you please let me know if the latest iText has been released ?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The slightly longer answer is that you could have found out by yourself if you had just looked for it on Maven Central or Github

Comment: @blagae : Hi, I am using Itext 7.1.8 version to convert a complex svg to pdf. I am noticing that some strokes are missing and the width attribute is not having any impact in the generated PDF. Can you please let me know if Itext has a fix for it ?

Comment: 1. Nobody can know if there's a fix if you don't (isolate and) fully describe the issue. 
2. I am no longer an employee of iText Software and have not been involved in the iText project for a while now; please contact iText professional support for specific queries.